# Start b clip after mixer transition ends

Tags: video-editing, mlt, melt-framework

I'm seeking to mix 2 clips, however, I'd like for clip2 to start after the mixer transition **ends**, not **begins**.

Essentially, this should mix clip1 with only clip2's frame 0.

I was wondering if there was a better alternative to my current workaround:

```
melt \
    clip1.mp4 \
    clip2.mp4 in=0 out=0 length=300 \
       -mix 300 -mixer luma \
    clip2.mp4
```

Perhaps there is something to pause clip2 at frame 0 for 300 frames?

(I'm doing this with 2 .mlt clips, but voiding the audio_index doesn't seem to work on mlt clips, thus I get a small audio jump for 1 frame, so this workaround isn't ideal)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set audio_index on .mlt virtual clips because audio_index is a property of the avformat producer, but MLT XML is read by the xml producer.
You can use the [hold producer](https://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/ProducerHold) to hold a frame and mute audio. It defaults to 25 frames duration; so use `out` to override it:

```
melt clip1.mp4 hold:clip2.mp4 frame=0 out=299 -mix 300 -mixer luma clip2.mp4
```

Comment: Although the hold position looks very promising, I believe I have encountered a bug, I am getting the first image, while it should look like the second: http://imgur.com/a/ieNVk.   As I mentioned, I am mixing mlt clips. I have tested the hold producer with mp4s, and the result came out perfectly, but unfortunately, not with the xml/mlts.